# What was the Seven Years' War about?

Tags: war, france, 18th-century

I have become obsessed with the history of France and no one can deny that  the Seven Years' War was a very important war to their history, but until the more popular wars of the last few centuries, there seems to be a lack of simple guides to  the Seven Years' War.

Can somebody explain to me, an idiot's guide to what the Seven Years' War war was?

Comment: Can you at least tell us what you found with your research and which part bothers you most on the Seven Years' War? This site is not designed to give you an idiot's guide on anything. Please show us your prior research and narrow down your question to a specific point that can be answered definitively. Otherwise, your question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: It was about seven years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... in my honest opinion the "Seven Year War" was two wars in one. One one hand it was the Prussian struggle with Austria to become an European major power and so the "Seven Year War" is called the Third Slesian War (There were three wars between Prussia and Austria for Slesian). Prussia was allied with Britain - Austria was allied with France and Russia (both had some minor allies - but you asked for an idiots guide so I will do it not too complicate).

So Britain and France were enemies they major battles was about the colonies. This - on the other hand - was the second part of the Seven Year War. The struggle between France and Britain about their oversea colonies.

See: http://www.history.com/topics/seven-years-war

Comment: That sounds spot on to me. France had by the time of the 7 Years War clearly surpassed Spain as the most powerful "State" in Europe. Since England seemed pretty small and didn't have much in the way of important overseas possessions going to War with England seemed like a slam dunk at the time I would argue. Turned into a disaster as France lost French Canada and ultimately the Monarchy.